# Delete users in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a function that deletes the current logged in user:

```
auth.currentUser.delete().then(logoutOfApp)
.catch((error) => alert(error)));
```

It works just fine, but I want to make someone an admin, so I would like him to have an option to delete other accounts, so is there a way to do something like this?

```
auth.something(UserID of the user that i want to delete).delete()
```

Comment: You have to do it backend with firebase-admin

Comment: The Firebase client-side SDKs (such as the one you're using in your ReactJS code) only allow the currently logged in user to delete their own account. There is no way for a user to delete somebody else's account, as that would be a security risk (and make the SDK even bigger than it already is). You will have to delete the user account on a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server that you control, or in Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use firebase-admin [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin) package in your backend;

```
app.get('/delete', function (req, res) {
 const sessionCookie = req.cookies.session || '';
 res.clearCookie('session');
 if (sessionCookie) {
  // Verify user and then delete the user.
  admin.auth().verifySessionCookie(sessionCookie, true).then(function(decodedClaims) {
   return admin.auth().deleteUser(userIdToDelete);
  })
  .then(function() {
   // Redirect to login page on success.
   res.redirect('/');
  })
  .catch(function() {
   // Redirect to login page on error.
   res.redirect('/');
  });
 } else {
  // Redirect to login page when no session cookie available.
  res.redirect('/');
 }
});
```